# Restreaming another nginx rtmp stream

Tags: python, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp, nginx-config

First of all, I'll explain what I want to achieve, because there might be even better way to achieve this.
I am looking at making 2 streams work, one is pushing to twitch.tv and youtube with delay and other one is live (without delay) that can be watched using VLC or whatever.

I am able to achieve this partially, but "live" stream just breaks sometimes randomly with this error:

```
Failed to update header with correct duration.
Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

Before, I had "Could not find codec parameters" error, but I solved it by adding this to my ffmpeg command:

```
-analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647
```

What I've already done is:

I made these rtmp server and apps in my nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    chunk_size 4096;

    application delay_live {
        live on;
        record off;
        push_reconnect 500ms;

        push rtmp://live-vie.twitch.tv/app/my_stream_key;
        push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_stream_key;

    }

    application live {
                    live on;
                    record off;
            }

    application delay {
        live on;
        record all;
        record_path /tmp/nginx;

        # Work with timestamp to know when to continue streaming
        record_suffix .flv;
        record_unique on;

        # Work with signals to know when to continue streaming
        #record_append on;

        exec_publish sudo sh /home/start.sh;
    }

    exec_static mkdir /tmp/nginx;   #Working dir. Must be consistend with the delayer.py
    }
}
```

On `exec_publish` I run this .sh script:

```
sudo screen -dmS delay bash -c "python /usr/local/nginx/sbin/delay/rtmp_stream_delayer.py; sleep 9999";
sleep 0.5;
sudo screen -dmS live bash -c "python /usr/local/nginx/sbin/live/rtmp_stream_live.py; sleep 9999";
```

Those two python scripts are a little bit changed script from this git:

https://github.com/sistason/rtmp_stream_delayer
Few things I changed there is I used ffmpeg instead of avconv to call the commands, and inside `rtmp_stream_live.py` I've set the same directory/file as `rtmp_stream_delayer.py` (so it basically uses same .flv file to stream live). `rtmp_stream_live.py` has delay set to 0. Also I added `-analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647` to my live stream ffmpeg call to avoid codec errors I previously had.

Full ffmpeg calls that I use:

`rtmp_stream_delayer.py`

```
subprocess.check_output('ffmpeg -re -i {0} -codec copy -f flv {1}'.format(filename, "rtmp://my_ip:port/delay_live").split())
```

`rtmp_stream_live.py`

```
subprocess.check_output('ffmpeg -re -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i /tmp/nginx/{0} -codec copy -f {1}'.format(filename, STREAM_DESTINATION).split())
```

I tried adding this ffmpeg flag, but it didn't help at all (codec errors are back again):

```
 flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize
```

Delay stream works like a charm and without any problems, but live stream randomly stops with update header errors, I haven't been able to trigger it myself, it just happens randomly!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Failed to update header with correct duration.` is a red herring. That will always print when the stream is disconnected.This issue you need to diagnose is a disconnect from the broadcaster, or the target.

Comment: @szatmary the thing is that other stream from the same files works like a charm. I ended up with simply pushing this stream to other rtmp application, instead of using ffmpeg... I'll add the answer now with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with simply pushing stream to another application. For some reason, I thought this wasn't allowed... So my config just looks like this now:

```
rtmp {
server {
   listen 1935;
   chunk_size 4096;

   application delay_live {
       live on;
       record off;
       push_reconnect 500ms;

       push rtmp://live-vie.twitch.tv/app/my_stream_key;
       push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_stream_key;

   }

   application live {
                  live on;
                  record off;
          }

   application delay {
       live on;
       record all;
       record_path /tmp/nginx;

       # Work with timestamp to know when to continue streaming
       record_suffix .flv;
       record_unique on;

       # Work with signals to know when to continue streaming
       #record_append on;

       push rtmp://localhost:1935/live;
       exec_publish sudo sh /home/start.sh;
       }

   exec_static mkdir /tmp/nginx;   #Working dir. Must be consistend with the delayer.py
   }
}
```

And I just have run delay stream with my python script using `start.sh` and opened live stream in vlc using `rtmp://localhost:1935/live/stream_key`